# Event Filtering before Lambda Invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I want to reduce traffic load on my lambda(listens to sqs) using the event source filtering -> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/filtering-event-sources-for-aws-lambda-functions/.
The challenge is the attribute i want to use is inside a attribute which is form of list.
eg :
{"a" : {"b" : [{"attr1":"val1"},{"attr1","val2"}]}} is the message from my sqs to lambda and i want to use attr1 for filtering. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: It looks like the criteria are specified using [Amazon EventBridge event patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns.html). Since your data has a _list_ of values, I presume that you are wanting to match on _any_ `attr1` value (not necessarily the first such value). I couldn't see any functions on that documentation page that can refer to "any values in a list".